# How to use sequelize migration models when querying?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have recently switched from "normal" sequelize to migrations with sequelize-cli. Using the cli worked fine so far. But I am unsure how to use the models that are generated. In particular it seems that the way I do it, I have issues with the associations. They are properly created in the database, but in the code I get errors like `Upvote is not associated to Video`

I have created the models with the cli and tried to import and use them.

This is a snippet of the `video` model generated by the cli:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Video = sequelize.define('Video', {
        userid: DataTypes.STRING,
        ...
    }, {});
    Video.associate = function(models) {
        Video.hasMany(models.Upvote, { foreignKey: 'videoid', sourceKey: 'id' });
    };
    return Video;
};
```

Here comes a snippet of the migration:

```
let videos = function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Videos', {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        userid: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            references: {
                model: 'Users',
                key: 'id'
            },
         },
         ...
     });
};
```

This is the way I import the models:

```
const Video = require('../models/video')(dbConnector.sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

I find it a little weird that I need to pass `sequelize` and `DataTypes`, since this was not necessary when I built the models myself. Is this the right way of importing them?
There is no error when I import them, and I can query them like `Videos.findAll()` but the associations don't work. And I am not sure how to make them work, do I need to call the `Video.associate(models)` function myself? That seems weird, too.

I must be doing something wrong in the way I use those models, please let me know what to do differently.

Comment: I have tried using sequelize migration and associating models in Postgresql. Take a look at this, https://github.com/praveenkumar-outlook/Sequelize-Postgres-Service

Comment: Ooooh I get it, you import the whole `models` directory, which contains an `index.js` where all the associations are called! If you write an answer with this I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize cli will generate an `index.js` inside `models` directory which will have the following code,

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === 
      '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
```

In the first set of code, it will import all models whereas in the second set, it will associate all models based on the association configured inside `associate` method of each and every model.

For Example, in your case, the association between `Video` and `Upvote` can be defined as,

models/Video.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Video = sequelize.define('Video', {
        id: DataTypes.STRING,
        ...
    }, {});
    Video.associate = function(models) {
        Video.hasMany(models.Upvote, {
            foreignKey: 'videoId',
            sourceKey: 'id'
        });
    };
    return Video;
};
```

models/Upvote.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Upvote = sequelize.define('Upvote', {
        id: DataTypes.STRING,
        videoId: DataTypes.STRING
        ...
    }, {});
    Upvote.associate = function(models) {
        Upvote.belongsTo(models.Video, {
            foreignKey: 'videoId',
            targetKey: 'id'
        });
    };
    return Upvote;
};
```

Hope this helps!!!